# Migrating Dynamodb Data between regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I've a requirement to copy and move (depend on the case) items between AWS Dyanmodb regions.
For example, let's say, there is a **USER** table in **ap-south-1** region and I want to move some items of it to the **us-east-1** region.

So is there any way to migrate the data from one region to another considering large data set in mind?
I've read this solution [https://tvernon.tech/blog/move-dynamodb-data-between-regions]. But I am not sure how feasible it would be with large dataset.

See, I am not talking about Global tables here, which gives multi-region replication as a feature.

Comment: I think global tables seems most logical.

Comment: The reason to not go with global tables is that it provides replication. Hence it will replicate the entire table. Although in my case, I just want to move/copy some data from one region to another. Hope, I am loud and clear about my requirement.

Comment: **can somebody please help me with above problem?**